# My checkbox and radio buttion is not being displayed in notepad++

Tags: css

After I used the css downloaded from the website to style my website, my radio button is disappeared. After deleting css my radio button became visible.
What css should I change to make the radio button work. 
Below are the code that i think are the errors.

I tryed to delete some classes, and think the below code causing the radio button to go missing suddenly:

```
input[type="checkbox"],
    input[type="radio"] {
        -moz-appearance: none;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -ms-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        margin-right: -2em;
        opacity: 0;
        width: 1em;
        z-index: -1;
    }

        input[type="checkbox"] + label,
        input[type="radio"] + label {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #fff;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 1em;
            font-weight: 400;
            padding-left: 2.4em;
            padding-right: 0.75em;
            position: relative;
        }

            input[type="checkbox"] + label:before,
            input[type="radio"] + label:before {
                -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
                -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
                font-family: FontAwesome;
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: normal;
                text-transform: none !important;
            }

            input[type="checkbox"] + label:before,
            input[type="radio"] + label:before {
                background: rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.25);
                border-radius: 3px;
                content: '';
                display: inline-block;
                height: 1.65em;
                left: 0;
                line-height: 1.58125em;
                position: absolute;
                text-align: center;
                top: 0;
                width: 1.65em;
            }

        input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before,
        input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
            background: #2e3842;
            color: #fff;
            content: '\f00c';
        }

        input[type="checkbox"]:focus + label:before,
        input[type="radio"]:focus + label:before {
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #21b2a6;
        }
input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
    border-radius: 3px;
}

input[type="radio"] + label:before {
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Comment: this isn't a programming question, it's a software/plugin problem

Comment: there's no php here neither, so how is this a php question?

Answer (score 0):

Below are code in php, not in cs.

My radio button and submit button and even the text which is update and delete cannot be displayed which is after ?> in the code

```
<form name="input" action="page4processupdate.php"method="post">
      <?php
      $seladmin= $_POST['fselect'];
      {
          $result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE AdminNo = '".$seladmin."'" );
      }

      echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Field</th><th>Value</th></tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
echo "<tr><td> Admin No</td><td><input type='text' name='uAdminNo' readonly='readonly' value='" . $row['AdminNo'] . "'></td></tr>";
 echo "<tr><td> Address </td><td><input type='text' name='uAddress' value='". $row['Address'] . "'></td></tr>";

$fgender = $row['Gender'];
 if ($fgender == "M") 
{
echo "<tr><td> Gender </td><td>Male<input type='radio' name='uGender' value='M' checked>";
echo "Female<input type='radio' name='uGender' value='F'></td></tr>";
 }
 else
{
echo "<tr><td> Gender </td><td>Male<input type='radio' name='uGender' value='M'>";
echo "Female<input type='radio' name='uGender' value='F' checked></td></tr>";
 }

 echo "<tr><td> Email </td><td><input type='text' name='uEmail' value='". $row['Email'] . "'></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td> Contact </td><td><input type='text' name='uContact' value='".$row['Contact'] . "'></td></tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($connection);

?>
Update<input type='radio' name='fAction' value='Update' checked> <br/>
Delete<input type='radio' name='fAction' value='Delete'> <br/>

      <input type="submit"value="Submit">
      </form>
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: i want my radiobutton to be displayed

Comment: as I can see, you should to get fatal error: syntax error

Comment: `      $seladmin= $_POST['fselect'];
      {` this line is hasn't valid syntax

Comment: if it isnt a valid syntax , why it work when i remove the cs away?

Comment: the code work perfectly after i remove the entire cs away. it can even store my data in wamp

Comment: how do you add css?

Comment: also, delete this lines:     -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;

Comment: only my button and text starting to appear , everything except the radio buton

Answer (score 0):

ty i found how to do i basically have to delete the entire code here, even if i remove the one you told me to remove it cannot work. so i basically remove the below code to make it work.

```
input[type="checkbox"],
    input[type="radio"] {
        -moz-appearance: none;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -ms-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        margin-right: -2em;
        opacity: 0;
        width: 1em;
        z-index: -1;
    }
```